# Programmatically set select (multiple) element value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, onclick

I want to populate a select field with onclick but i don't know how to filter the array to only the value of the clicked button. With my code all the array objects populate the input and I want only the value of the clicked button to populate the input. Any hints?

```
<input type="hidden" id="id_user" value="{{user.id}}"> 
    <select id="id_entities" class="js-example-programmatic" style="width:100%" multiple="multiple">
    {% for teu in tagEntityUsers %}
        <option value="{{teu.entity_id}}" class="js-programmatic-set-val">{{teu.entity}}</option> 
    {% endfor %}
    </select>

 {% for teu in tagEntityUsers %}
  <tr>
    <td><a href="/entities/{{teu.entity_id}}/{{teu.entity.slug}}">{{teu.entity}}</a></td>
    <td><a href="{{ teu.user.get_absolute_url }}">{{teu.user}}</a></td>
    <td><button id ="{{teu.entity_id}}" class="js-programmatic-set-val" value="{{teu.entity_id}}" onclick="populate_box(this.id)">add entity</button></td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}

<script>
var $example = $(".js-example-programmatic");
var arr = $.map($('.js-programmatic-set-val'), function (el) { return el.value; });
function populate_box() {
    $example.val(this.arr).trigger("change"); }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll add a prefix to button id and set jQuery listener to it:

```
$("button[id^='prefix_']").click(function(){
   value = $(this).attr('data-value');
   $('#id_entities option[value="' + value + '"]').prop("selected", true).change();
});
```

So, the button will be:

```
<button id="prefix_{{teu.entity_id}}" class="js-programmatic-set-val" data-value="{{teu.entity_id}}">add entity</button>
```

**UPD**: Code above is fixed, [see it in action](http://jsbin.com/hilevorohu/edit?html,css,js,output). And I highly recommend to change `value` attribute on button to `data-value`, [read more about data-* attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)

Comment: thanks dr.dimitru but is not working.. after i change to your example nothing happens when the button is clicked

Comment: Could you `console.log(value)` after this line: `value = $(this).attr('value');`, make sure there is some correct value

Comment: if i do console.log(value) it outputs the correct values for each clicked button in the console.. but nothing happens in the input field

Comment: ok it works.. i forgot to add also $example.val(value).trigger("change"); part to your code..